# Strange behavior with hyperlink on iPad only

Tags: ios, html, ipad, hyperlink

My first post/question. Hope I don't stomp on any rules!

I have a site (mainly html5) with the same 9 "navigation" links on every page. They work exactly as expected in Safari, FF, Chrome on my **desktop** Mac. They also work correctly on my **iPhone 5**. However, while they all work, as far as taking the viewer from one page to another, on my iPad (2?), all but one have to be tapped/clicked on **twice** before they work. The *exception* is the "**Forecast**" page which works exactly like it should (single tap/click). I have checked all the pages with BBEdit's syntax checker and its "Compare..." function. I have also used the nu HTML validation service. None of these systems can explain why only one link works correctly on the iPad.

If you have an iPad, you can see what is happening better than I can explain it. http://www.mid-southweather.com/

Thanks for any help or insight. I've found nothing from interweb searches.

Comment: Hi Jim, I just tested your site on an iPad 2 running iOS 8 and all links worked as expected.

Comment: I am guessing that the iPad has some accessibility settings on which are causing this behavior.  Go to your iPads settings and look at what is enabled under the accessibility settings.

Comment: Thanks for the "test", **dsatch**! I did the same on my wife's iPad (3?), and things work normally! DOH! The one things I hadn't checked!! I'll also check the settings area, **Kris**. Another thing will be to find out how to dump the _History/Cache_ on the iPad, so simple on _real_ computers! 8+|. At least I can stop staring at the code looking for stray bits! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the iPad's Safari cache did not help, but I discovered, however, that the iPhone and iPad are sharing bookmarks or history! I'll clear things on the iPhone and try again.

No change, even after turning OFF Safari on both the iPad and iPhone iCloud list.

I suspect it is either the older iPad hardware or the CSS menu building 'code'. I found the same problem in an older site where I used the same CSS for a multi-level menu. The same two-tap requirement occurs at the lower/final link, but, again, only with my iPad. Oh well, thanks for testing/reading!

Comment: Problem is now gone, suspect upgrading the iOS? I have seen some other peculiarities in the same site on the desktop vs iDevices.